# $|[x]^{\lt \kappa}| = |x|^{\lt \kappa} ?$

Tags: set-theory

I want to know whether $|[x]^{\lt \kappa}| = |x|^{\lt \kappa}$ holds or not.

I know $|[x]^{\lt \kappa}| \leq |x|^{\lt \kappa}$ holds. The reason is following:
There exist a order $\leq$ so that $\langle x, \leq \rangle$ become well-ordered.
For each $y \in [x]^{\lt \kappa}$, there is only one order isomorphism $f_y$ : type($x, \leq$) $\rightarrow x$.
$f_y \in {^{\lt \kappa}}x$. and $F : [x]^{\lt \kappa} \rightarrow {^{\lt \kappa}}x, y \mapsto f_y$ is injection.

However I don't know $\geq$ holds or not. Because $G : {^{\lt \kappa}}x \rightarrow [x]^{\lt \kappa}, f \mapsto \text{range}(f)$ is not injection necessarily.

---

Notice:
System of this site alerted to me that this question might be duplicate of already existing question $|[\kappa]^\lambda| = \kappa^\lambda$.
But that is wrong. Difference is whether '$\lt$' exist as exponential or not.

Comment: Notice: $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\bigcup\{\kappa^\mu\mid\mu<\lambda\}$. So $|\kappa^{<\lambda}|=\lambda\cdot|\sup\{|\kappa^\mu|\mid\mu<\lambda\}$. So, it is in fact a duplicate, with just one more small step.

Comment: could you tell me more detailer proof?